# Why JsonSerializer doesn't have Serialize Method but have Create in Asp.Net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

Why JsonSerializer doesn't have Serialize Method but have Create in Asp.Net core ?

Have added a namespace but Syste.Text.Json but didn't work.

any idea

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct class? [System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=net-7.0) doesn't have a `Create` method. It does have a `Serialize` method with several overloads.

Comment: Are you trying to use the JSON.NET serializer class instead of the System.Text.Json class? The [JSON.NET JsonSerializer class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer.htm) does have a static Create method. Its Serialize method is a member, not a static method

Comment: oh, Ok I don't see System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer coming up.  what nugget package I need ?

Comment: None. You need to remove the extra package you added. .NET Core includes System.Text.Json by default and uses it for API serialization. You have to explicitly add the Json.NET package to get the JSON.NET serializer class. Decide which class you really want and either remove the JSON.NET package or don't try to use System.Text.Json in your code. If you need to use both, make sure you use the correct class each time, eg by using the correct namespace in the `using` directives or using the full namespace in the calls

Comment: Removing System.json.Text namespace didn't work.

Comment: It's JSON.NET you need to remove. You're trying to use System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer but end up trying to use Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer. Most likely you have a `using Newtonsoft.Json;` clause in your file

Comment: Yes I just removed Newton.json and it worked. Thank much!!